# Archive area in local CRAN

Tags: r, package, cran

My organization has a local [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/)-like repository for internal R packages.  As we release more and more packages, I want to retire old versions to an Archive area so that people can get to them if they really want them, but by default they won't be installed by `install.packages()` and the like.

Is the best practice to just move them into `src/contrib/Archive`?  Will that play well with the indexing routines like `write_PACKAGES()`?  I use subdirectories for each distinct package, so somehow it needs to know not to descend into this directory.

Comment: interesting (to me at least) but seems inappropriate for SO.  I would recommend R-devel ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maintenance of an R package repository (i.e. not really about R programming)


Comment: My intention is to ask about what the standard R tools expect - i.e. will `install.packages()` and/or `write_PACKAGES()` "see" the archived packages or not.  I can of course just try it but I thought this would be a good way to get a Definitive Answer Put On The Internet.

Comment: did you find a good solution on that? I face the same question, plus I would like to save as well the windows bin version of the packages

Comment: I didn't really find a sanctioned solution, but what I do is create an `archive` directory at the same level as `bin` and `src`, and move packages to there when I want to retire them from public view.  They're still around if someone wants to manually browse for them, and they don't seem to cause any trouble.